# JPanel move node location - repaint not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

[image]

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight());
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            System.out.println("down");
            ball.moveY(5);
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            System.out.println("up");
            ball.moveY(-5);
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            System.out.println("left");
            ball.moveX(-5);
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            System.out.println("right");
            ball.moveX(5);
        }
        System.out.println("X: " +ball.getX() +", Y: " +ball.getY());
        repaint();
    }
```

When I press an arrow key and move the `ball`, why doesn't the `repaint()` method erase the ball's location from before? It's creating a tail thing.

Thanks

Comment: you should call `super.paintComponent(g)` and use keybindings over keylisteners

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting to call the super's paintComponent. i.e.,

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight());
}
```

Note

- that paintComponent should be protected, not public. Also, don't forget the `@Override` annotation.
- KeyListeners should be avoided for Swing applications. Key Bindings are in general preferred since they are "higher level" concepts.

Comment: @growler Check out [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting works in Swing

Comment: +1 good advices, not related to this question but should use `KeyBinding` over `KeyListener`, cause now he have to make that panel focusable and be in focus

Comment: @MadProgrammer: no, don't delete your answer as it provides different info. And I 1+'d it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's true, it was a good answer too... the paintComponent chain was a good one xD

Answer (score 4):

Because you've broken the paint chain.

One of the jobs that `paintComponent` does is to clear the `Graphics` context of what ever was painted to it before.

Make sure you call `super.paintComponent` first

Generally, the `Graphics` context is a shared resource, this means that everything that was painted during a paint cycle will share the same `Graphics` context.  It also means that it's possible that the same `Graphics` context will be used for a single native peer (as is the case for you).  You must always make best efforts to clean the context before use (transparency being a special case)

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting is done in Swing

As has already being suggested, it is recommended that you use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`, the most significant reasons is because the key bindings API gives you greater control of the level of focus required before a key event is triggered

Answer (score 0):

You are forget to call super.paintComponent(g). Have a look at [PaintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Try to replace

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight());
    }
```

By

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight());
    }
```